# Writing JSON with dict properties to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

Using Apache Beam(Python 2.7 SDK) I am trying to write JSON files as entities into Google Cloud Datastore.

Sample JSON:

```
{
"CustId": "005056B81111",
"Name": "John Smith", 
"Phone": "827188111",
"Email": "john@xxx.com", 
"addresses": [
    {"type": "Billing", "streetAddress": "Street 7", "city": "Malmo", "postalCode": "CR0 4UZ"},
    {"type": "Shipping", "streetAddress": "Street 6", "city": "Stockholm", "postalCode": "YYT IKO"}
]
}
```

I have written a Apache Beam pipeline with mainly 3 steps,

1. beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file_path)
2. beam.ParDo(CreateEntities())
3. WriteToDatastore(PROJECT)

In step 2, I am converting JSON object(dict) into an entity,

```
class CreateEntities(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    element = element.encode('ascii','ignore')
    element = json.loads(element)
    Id = element.pop('CustId')
    entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
    datastore_helper.add_key_path(entity.key, 'CustomerDF', Id)
    datastore_helper.add_properties(entity, element)
    return [entity]
```

This works fine for basic properties. However since address is a dict object itself it fails.
I have read a similar [post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/3361).

However did not get the exact code to convert dict -> entity

Tried below to set address element as entity but does not work,

```
element['addresses'] = entity_pb2.Entity()
```

Other References:

- https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/uploading-data-cloud-datastore-using-dataflow/
- https://gcloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastore/entities.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to store this as a repeated structured property?

`ndb.StructuredProperty`s appear in dataflow with the keys flattened, and for repeated structured properties, each individual property within the structured property object becomes an array. So I think you would need to write it like this:

```
datastore_helper.add_properties(entity, {
    ...
    "addresses.type": ["Billing", "Shipping"],
    "addresses.streetAddress": ["Street 7", "Street 6"],
    "addresses.city": ["Malmo", "Stockholm"],
    "addresses.postalCode": ["CR0 4UZ", "YYT IKO"],
})
```

Alternatively, if youre trying to save this as a ndb.JsonProperty, you can do this:

```
datastore_helper.add_properties(entity, {
        ...
        "addresses": json.dumps(element['addresses']),
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I am trying to use NDB now. For which I import NDB using command,  "from google.appengine.ext import ndb"                                                For that when i try to do 'pip install google.appengine.ext' it fails saying 
    "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google.appengine.ext (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for google.appengine.ext"    

The I did,
    "gcloud components install app-engine-python"

But still the same error.

Comment: Oh ndb can only be used from app engine standard. But i assumed you have an app engine app that youre trying to send these records to

Comment: no I'm not using an AppEngine. I am running an Apache Beam pipeline with Python(2.7) SDK. This pipeline tires to read .JSON files from Cloud Storage and writes them to Cloud Datastore. So from your reply it seems that ndb cannot be used then.

Comment: Right, but once these records are in datastore. How do you plan to read/use them?

Comment: yes for that we have an AppEngine to access records from Datastore. It is built using Node.js. So is there anything that I can try to fix this issue with Apache Beam?

Comment: Either of the 2 methods in my original answer should work. The one you choose impacts how you need to read the data back out.

Comment: i guess converting list to str should solve it, therefore I use your advice to do element['addresses'] = json.dumps(element['addresses']), but I get below error,         
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: I am getting the error "raise TypeError('value type: %r not supported' % (value,))" from the "set_value" method of the "google-cloud-datastore/python/googledatastore/helper.py" script. Somehow list properties are not working with this script. Really need some advice here.

Comment: Just to add, simple list like [1,2,3] works but [{"value":"1"},{"value":"2"},{"value":"3"}] doesn't. Basically a list of dict object doesn't work. Is there some workaround?

Comment: wrap your list in a dict `json.dumps({'values':[{"value":"1"},{"value":"2"},{"value":"3"}]})`

Comment: 'json.dumps' sets the Datastore entity property type to 'String' as expected instead of 'Array'. I did something like this "unicode(json.dumps([{"value":"1"},{"value":"2"},{"value":"3"}]))" Note that I can only manipulate the values and not the property itself, otherwise property name 'values' comes in the value as well. String is somewhat good but Array was ideal. With this i have to convert the String back to Array while querying in APIs

Comment: I worked around this problem by making using of python client libraries for datastore, instead of using Datastore helper libraries. 

            dsclient = datastore.Client(PROJECT)
            score_entity = datastore.Entity(key=<some key>)
            score_entity.update(element)
            dsclient.put(score_entity)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar issue (although Python 3.6 and NDB) and wrote a function to convert all `dicts` inside a `dict` into `Entity`. This uses recursion to go through all nodes converting as necessary:

```
def dict_to_entity(data):

    # the data can be a dict or a list, and they are iterated over differently
    # also create a new object to store the child objects
    if type(data) == dict:
        childiterator = data.items()
        new_data = {}
    elif type(data) == list:
        childiterator = enumerate(data)
        new_data = []
    else:
        return

    for i, child in childiterator:

        # if the child is a dict or a list, continue drilling...
        if type(child) in [dict, list]:
            new_child = dict_to_entity(child)
        else:
            new_child = child

        # add the child data to the new object
        if type(data) == dict:
            new_data[i] = new_child
        else:
            new_data.append(new_child)

    # convert the new object to Entity if needed
    if type(data) == dict:
        child_entity = datastore.Entity()
        child_entity.update(new_data)
        return child_entity
    else:
        return new_data
```

Comment: Hey I'm still pretty new to datastore. How would you use it in a Dataflow Pipeline? Could you point me to any documentation please?